# dell p2419h ubuntu 75 hertz

Tags: dell, 21.04

I have a Dell p2419h monitor and Ubuntu 21.04. Right now I have a maximum 60 hertz that I can set the monitor to. It should be 75. I did not find any information about drivers for Ubuntu or any recommendation or user guide. 60 hertz is not comfortable for eyes. Can my monitor work with 75 hertz on 1920x1080?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Can my monitor work with 75 hertz on 1920x1080?

No, it can't, according to the manufacturer's published [specifications](https://www.dell.com/en-hr/work/shop/cty/pdp/spd/dell-p2419h-monitor):

> Maximum Preset Resolution
> 1920 x 1080 at 60 Hz

Regarding your assertion "60 hertz is not comfortable for eyes" citations are needed. Most FHD monitors works at 60Hz and users don't complain. Even if that was the case - it isn't - asserting that an higher frequency would somehow improve it has no scientific basis.

Comment: but dell publish `Refresh Rate 75 Hz` for this model or it's mistake ?

Comment: No, not a mistake, just a misunderstanding. 75Hz can be achieved with lower than the native (and recommended) resolution.